# point domain to dedicated server and configure DNS

Tags: nginx, dns, debian, cpanel, dedicated

For various reasons, I have had to move from my managed hosting to a dedicated server setup. The dedicated server now runs Debian 7.0 and I have installed and secured the server using basic tools such as fail2ban and iptables.

I do not want to run any mailservers, and would simply like to serve webapps on this machine. However, I do not seem to know/understand how to point my domain (from namecheap) to this machine and configure DNS records (if this is required). I am normally use Nginx as my production server.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me to some good tutorials/handouts which explain how to point my name to my dedicated machine and set up DNS - I did try google, but havent found any reliable instructions.

I do not want instructions for plesk/cpanel/webmin - I would like to learn by editing and configuring files.

Answer (score 0):

You should log-in to your namecheap and get the 2 nameserver of your hosting provider to update or to point your nameservers to your hosting. And check your host record on your dns config then try to make TTL to 1hr. So if you try to ping your domain it should be your hosting provider IP not your domain registrant.